# I don't want to use a copy constructor in synchronized queue

Tags: c++, constructor, copy

This pop method needs a copy constructor. But I don't want to have this. I want that no constructor or the move constructor of the item is called. How must I implement it?

```
auto pop() {
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(mutex_);
    cond_.wait(lock, [this]() {return queue_.empty() == false; });

    T& item = queue_.front();
    queue_.pop();

    return item;
}
```

T& item = queue_.front() requies a copy constructor after the compiler error message.

Comment: the quesiton is unclear. Is `queue_` a `std::queue` ? `std::queue::front()` does not require copy nor move. Please post a [mcve], and include the compiler error in the question. I guess the issue you are having is actually from `return item`.

Comment: There's no way to utilise copy ellision when you have to both remove element from container and pass it to somewhere else. It has to be copied or moved.

Comment: In some way the "ownership" of the data has to be passed back from the queue to the caller (because after a pop, the queue is no longer the owner of the data). That includes, copy move or some modeling of shared ownership of the items in the queue (e.g. shared_ptr).

Comment: `item` is a dangling reference after you called `queue_.pop()`. And `auto` return type is not deduced as reference, I suppose thats the error you currently face. Though that error saved you from more serious trouble.

Comment: @463035818_is_not_an_ai No auto does not resolve to an `int&` it resolves to `int`. That's way `return item;` will try to construct a new T using the copy constructor. See ; https://onlinegdb.com/krpFCIFsc

Comment: @PepjinKramer what I said. I guess OP expects it to be deduced as reference, but we can only guess. They say `queue_.front();` would require a copy but thats certainly a misunderstanding

Comment: @463035818_is_not_an_ai Indeed we can only assume, and I do agree resolving to an `int&` would have hidden worse issues.

Comment: If you don't want constructors of `T` to be called, one way would be to store `std::unique_ptr<T>` in the queue instead and return that pointer.

Answer (score 7):

> I want that no constructor or the move constructor of the item is called

Then you must make your code satisfy the conditions for return value optimization. It's a non-guaranteed form of copy elision that allows the compiler to either

- Create no temporary return object.
- If impossible, just move into the return object.

To accomplish that, you must return a local object, not a reference. In the code snippet you've shown, this is the minimal change to accomplish that:

```
T item = std::move(queue_.front());
```

We extract the item from the queue by moving, so move only types can work here.

When we do `return item;` it satisfies the conditions for return value optimization, and the return object is at most moved again whenever possible.